# Where can I get the latest PAM source code?

Tags: 16.04

There is a new version of libpam-modules for Xenial, namely 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.**1**. Where can I get the source code? Thank you in advance.

My previous source:
https://git.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/pam/

Comment: For packages in Ubuntu, you should probably install the `ubuntu-dev-tools` package, and then use `pull-lp-source` to download the source packages.

Comment: `pull-lp-source libpam-modules 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1` gives `pull-lp-source: Downloading libpam-modules version 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1` `pull-lp-source: Error: Failed to download: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libpam-modules_1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1.dsc: 404 Not Found`

Comment: The source package is `pam` and not `libpam-modules`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get source pam
```

For more info:

```
man apt-get
```

Additionally, you can install the build dependencies by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pam
```